# What should i do to access variable 'a'?

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
#include<iostream>
int a;    //1st a
void f()
{
   int a;    //2nd a

   {
        int a;   //3rd a
 // ::a refers to the global a here
 // simply a refers to the a inside this namespace


//What should i do to access and modify 2nd a here in this namespace

   }

}
```

I am aware that to access global names i need to use ::a but what should i do if the name i want to access is inside a function and i am inside the namespace defined by that function?

Comment: Why are you using the same name that will be visible at multiple levels? C++ allows plenty of characters for variable and type names. It's ridiculous not to use different names in order to make the code readable and maintainable and avoid stupid mistakes because of scoping issues.

Comment: @KenWhite i know i shouldnt do that i just wanted to learn about this

Comment: @rimiro You cannot access the second declaration of `a` since it's shadowed by the 3rd declaration.

Comment: @user0042 but i can access 1st declaration and why it is not shadowed while 2nd declaration is

Comment: @rimiro You can access the 1st declaration because it's accessible using the global scope operator (`::`), but that's not possible for the 2nd declaration.

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax to access the second `a` from the inner scope. You would have to create a unique alias beforehand, e.g.:

```
void f()
{
     int a;
     {
          int& outer_a = a;
          int a;
```

Comment: please can you state your second statement clearly i am not getting that

Answer (score -1):

You can only access 2nd `a` inside the function scope.